# Elastic Beanstalk /ondeck not updating /current and still showing 404?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront

I currently have a Rails 4.0.3 repo with Ruby 2.1.1.  I am trying to deploy this on my EB environment.  Everything seems to be working fine, no errors are thrown when I run:

```
eb start
git aws.push
```

But If I SSH into my server, I see that my `/var/app/ondeck` has not updated with my git repository even if I run `git aws.push --environment myenv`.

I see the current git revision hash on my dashboard when I aws.push, but the repo code never gets to the server...

The other issue is that fact that my /var/app/current is still empty. Any ideas?

After running a `git aws.push`, the only thing that gets logged is:

```
2014-04-02 05:45:02,567 [INFO] (5874 MainThread) [clearStaleLogPublishingRecords.py-38] [root clearStaleLogPublishingRecords main] Clearing stale log publish records publish log task with batch id ef7dd76a-ba29-11e3-bf20-12313913dae2
2014-04-02 05:45:02,568 [INFO] (5874 MainThread) [clearStaleLogPublishingRecords.py-48] [root clearStaleLogPublishingRecords main] Successfully cleared stale log publishing records
2014-04-02 05:50:01,874 [INFO] (5887 MainThread) [publishLogs.py-61] [root publishLogs main] Starting publish log task with batch id a1e453b6-ba2a-11e3-86ba-12313913dae2
2014-04-02 05:50:01,991 [INFO] (5887 MainThread) [publishLogs.py-86] [root publishLogs main] Log publication is disabled
```

After running `eb update` nothing gets put to the logs.

These also help describe the issue:

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=336101
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=357003

However, I have the latest command line eb, and have tried detaching the HEAD from the git repo and then checking out the master and pushing again, still no luck :(

Also tried "upload and deploy" a zip version from the control panel, nothing got updated.

```
2014-04-02 08:12:22,185 [ERROR] (1895 MainThread) [directoryHooksExecutor.py-34] [root directoryHooksExecutor error] Script failed with returncode 1
2014-04-02 08:12:22,246 [INFO] (1872 MainThread) [command.py-130] [root command execute] Command returned: (code: 1, stdout: Error occurred during build: Command hooks failed
, stderr: None)
2014-04-02 08:12:22,248 [DEBUG] (1872 MainThread) [commandWrapper.py-60] [root commandWrapper main] Command result: {'status': 'FAILURE', 'results': [{'status': 'FAILURE', 'config_sets': ['Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild', 'Hook-PreAppDeploy', 'Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild'], 'returncode': 1, 'events': [], 'msg': 'Error occurred during build: Command hooks failed\n'}], 'api_version': '1.0'}
```

Comment: Worth checking /var/log/eb-tools.log (or via the snapshot logs) for clues.

Comment: Thanks @Shadwell, I ran those commands and this is what I get... Updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched to a Ruby 2.0 running Rails 4.0.3 on the oregon datacenter (west-2), and it seems to be pushing fine.  I do think it had something to do with a hook failing.  For instance, if you have additional hooks or commands that require GIT, and git isn't installed on the server, it will fail silently or scream... That seems to have been what was going on here.